# peewee orm: Join three tables with foreign keys, counting middle table

Tags: sql, postgresql, peewee

I have the following peewee tables/classes (on a postgres DB) and below the dashed line, an example of what I'd like.

Basically I'm a complete newb at DB queries and have no idea how to structure it: I need, given a list of days (like ['2015-01-01', ...]) to obtain the number of Alerts on each day (if there were any) as a count per Service. Hopefully the example below is clear enough.

```
class Event(BaseModel):
    assessment = CharField(max_length = 4096)
    day = DateField()
    ongoing = BooleanField()
    alertType = CharField(null = True)
    links = CharField(null = True, max_length = 4096)
    newLinks = CharField(null = True, max_length = 4096)
    startTime = TimeField()
    endTime = TimeField(null = True)

class Service(BaseModel):
    svcid = TextField(unique = True)
    name = TextField()

class Alert(BaseModel):
    alertId = CharField(unique = True, null = True)
    alertLink = CharField(unique = True, null = True)
    startTime = TimeField()
    endTime = TimeField(null = True)
    jcaLink = CharField(max_length = 4096, null = True)
    description = CharField(max_length = 4096)
    relatedNodes = CharField(null = True)
    customerName = CharField(null = True)
    jcaUrl = CharField(null = True)
    deviceName = CharField(null = True)
    event = ForeignKeyField(Event, related_name = 'alerts')
    service = ForeignKeyField(Service, related_name = 'alerts')
    hosted = CharField(default = None, null = True)

------------------------------------------------------------

Example: Event.id 1 has Event.day '2015-01-01'
         Event.id 2 has Event.day '2015-01-02'
         Service.id 1 has name "A"
         Service.id 2 has name "B"
         Alert.id 1 has Alert.event.id 1, Alert.service.id 1
         Alert.id 2 has Alert.event.id 2, Alert.service.id 2
         Alert.id 3 has Alert.event.id 2, Alert.service.id 1
         # end of db

If days is ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02'], output should be like (not resembling, just broken up/organized somewhat like)
Service A
day 2015-01-01 
1 alert
day 2015-01-02
1 alert
-----------------
Service B
day 2015-01-01
1 alert
day 2015-01-02
0 alerts
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I am not sure if your model adds columns like `s.id` but I imagine it does. Your start_time is a time field so I use the `date()` method so we are just comparing date parts.

```
select s.name, date(a.start_time) as alert_date, count(s.name) as alerts
from alert a join service s on a.service_id = s.id
where date(a.start_time) in ('2015-01-01', '2015-01-02')
group by s.name, alert_date
```

Note that when doing a group by, all fields selected must be used in a group by or aggregate function. There are ways around this but since you need such little data it was not necessary however I am assuming that `service.name` is unique.

Also, if you want to get alerts by month, year, etc. you can use `extract` like this:

```
select s.name, extract(month from a.start_time) as alert_month, 
extract(year from a.start_time) as alert_year, count(s.name) as alerts
from alert a join service s on a.service_id = s.id
where extract(year from a.start_time) = 2015
and extract(month from a.start_time) in (11, 12)
group by s.name, alert_month, alert_year
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but Alert.startTime doesn't have date information, just times like 'HH:MM'.

I fiddled around and got [this](http://pastebin.com/a5QThpTH), the generated SQL is about halfway down. The only thing I'm missing is 0s for days when Services didn't have any alerts.

Comment: I see, the date is in event.day. What ORM are you using? Try changing your inner joins to left joins.

Comment: I'm using the peewee orm: http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

As for changing the join with JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, it doesn't QUITE do what I want; it adds null values for the days, not the counts of Alerts.

Comment: Does adding a where clause like `and "t3"."day" is not null` or `.where(Event.day.is_null(False))` work? When you need sql help creating an example at http://sqlfiddle.com/ is very helpful.